# CanJS EJS table - rows appearing above the table

Tags: ejs, canjs, canjs-view

I am new to CanJS and was trying to learn via tutorials.. Once place where I got stuck was when I converted the [todo tutorial code](http://jsfiddle.net/donejs/5zpFz/) to use table instead of UL/LI combination.

May be I am making some very small mistake.. but could not find out the same for last 3 days.. Can someone help out?

The jsFiddle for the short version of todo tutorial (which now uses tables) is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dharapvj/5zpFz/92/) where you can see the problems.

The crux of the code from ejs is here..

```
<script type='text/ejs' id='todosEjs'>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<!-- bind to changes in the todo list -->
<% this.each(function( todo ) { %> 
    <!-- add the todo to the element's data -->
    <tr <%= (el) -> el.data('todo',todo) %>>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" <%= todo.attr('complete') ? 'checked' : '' %>>
        </td>
        <td><%= todo.attr('name') %></td>
        <td><%= todo.attr('id') %></td>
    </tr>
<% }) %>
 </tbody>
</table>

</script>
```

Looking forward towards helping hands :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE: This was the result of [a bug](https://github.com/bitovi/canjs/issues/271) which is now fixed**

It looks as if the comments are the problem here. Removing them makes it work, see [the updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zpFz/93/):

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>status</th>
    </tr>
<% this.each(function( todo ) { %> 
    <tr <%= (el) -> el.data('todo',todo) %>>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" <%= todo.attr('complete') ? 'checked' : '' %>>
        </td>
        <td><%= todo.attr('name') %></td>
        <td><%= todo.attr('id') %></td>
    </tr>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: Thanks Dude! Could have never thought that the comment was the culprit!